# CRS registry definition issues (EPSG:3035)

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I am performing analysis on one of the flood risk raster maps found on https://data.jrc.ec.europa.eu/dataset/1d128b6c-a4ee-4858-9e34-6210707f3c81#dataaccess.

When I try to clip the data to Austria via "clip to view", I obtain the following warning:

**Warning 1: The definition of projected CRS EPSG:3035 got from GeoTIFF keys is not the same as the one from the EPSG registry, which may cause issues during reprojection operations. Set GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE configuration option to EPSG to use official parameters (overriding the ones from GeoTIFF keys), or to GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys and drop the EPSG code.**

As I am new to QGIS, I don't really understand what's going on and where this issue originates. An internet research was to no avail. Should I take the warning serious? Or can I expect everything to work downstream if I ignore the warning? If I should adress it, how can I do so?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at `floodMap_RP200` from your link, the issue is with the data.

```
gdalinfo floodmap_EFAS_RP200_C.tif

Reports that the data is in EPSG:3035 like:


Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: floodmap_EFAS_RP200_C.tif
       floodmap_EFAS_RP200_C.tif.ovr
       floodmap_EFAS_RP200_C.tif.aux.xml
Size is 63976, 45242
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["ETRS_1989_LAEA",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
        METHOD["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9820]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",52,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",10,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",4321000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",3210000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",3035]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
```

but the EPSG registry tells us that [CRS 3035](https://epsg.org/crs_3035/ETRS89-extended-LAEA-Europe.html?) has axes of Northing, then Easting, so if the data is in easting/northing order (as reported) it is not in fact in EPSG:3035.

You should therefore

Set GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys and drop the EPSG code.

Comment: How would I "Set GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys and drop the EPSG code." ?

Answer (score 5):

What is stored into GeoTIFF tags can be listed with gdalinfo:

```
gdalinfo floodmap_EFAS_RP010_C.tif
...
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["ETRS_1989_LAEA",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
        METHOD["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9820]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",52,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",10,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",4321000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",3210000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",3035]]
```

The current definition of EPSG:3035 can be checked from the EPSG registry https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/3035 and it can also be printed with gdalsrsinfo.

```
gdalsrsinfo epsg:3035

PROJCRS["ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["Europe Equal Area 2001",
        METHOD["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9820]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",52,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",10,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",4321000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",3210000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",3035]]
```

You can see that there are some differences:

PROJCRS["ETRS_1989_LAEA" vs. PROJCRS["ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe",
CONVERSION["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area" vs. CONVERSION["Europe Equal Area 2001"

and

```
AXIS["(E)",east,
             ORDER[1],
             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
         AXIS["(N)",north,
             ORDER[2],
```

vs.

```
AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
             ORDER[1],
             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
         AXIS["easting (X)",east,
             ORDER[2],
```

If you want to be sure that the clipped image matches correctly with the original one now and in the future, use the "GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys" option. Or if you find that the difference in georeferencing is small, you may consider to update the CRS of the original image with gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html `-a_srs epsg:3035`.